# Is the java Garbage collector responsible to release the JMS connection after connection.close()

Tags: java, garbage-collection, connection, jms, release

I am using GlassFish JMS ConnectionFactory. Connection is closed in finally. and Maximum Pool Size is set to 5.

**Test Case:** I sent 10 messages constantly within 3 seconds from invoker().

**Result:** First 5 messages sent successfully and message 6 onward failed to allocate more connections. It means all previous 5 connections were still open.

**Question 1:**  How long does it take to release the connection poll after connection.close()?

**Question 2:**  Is the Garbage collector responsible to release the connection after JMS connection.close()?

This is my simple message client which sends messages to the queue

private void invoker(String id){

```
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer messageProducer = null;
    TextMessage message = null;
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        messageProducer = session.createProducer(successfulQueue);
        String msg = id;
        message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
        messageProducer.send(message);
        log.info("Successful message is Sent to ProcessQueue: [" + msg + "]");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    finally {
        if (messageProducer != null) {
            try {
                messageProducer.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's the `Garbage Collector` not the `JMS Connection Releaser`, so take a guess.

Comment: Thanks for reply, So what is the best approach to avoid the allocation failure ?

Comment: Well, I suspect you're doing a lot of wrong things. First of all you say that this is your `MDB`, which is wrong. A Message Driven Bean is executed to *handle* a message. Your code isn't handling messages, it's sends a message.

Comment: Noted with thanks. Just to amend my post this is a simple message client which sends messages to a queue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your 2nd Question is The Connection is not closed by the GC but instead the background process that KeepsAlive the connection is terminated by `connection.close()`
(For How GC works read: https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-work-in-the-JVM)

Recommendation: Try using A *PooledConnectionFactory* and do a .stop() on the same apart from connection.close

```
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    if (connection != null || pcf != null) try {
          connection.close();
    //pcf.stop();
    }
    catch (JMSException e) {
         //log
    }
```